# Variables no inicializádas

Tags: c++

Les explicaré lo mejor que pueda:

Tengo estas funciones, en las cuales uso memoria dinámica para ordenar un vector y luego mostrarlo (Este es el orden exacto en el que tengo las funciones en mi proyecto) :

```
int contar_registros(int pos)
{
   if (pos == 1)
 {
        FILE *pc;
        int bytes;
        pc = fopen (FILE_CARRERA, "rb");
        if (pc == NULL)
        {
    return -1;
        }
    fseek (pc,0,2);
    bytes = ftell (pc);
    fclose (pc);

    return bytes / sizeof (struct carrera);
}

if (pos == 2)
{
    FILE *pc;
    int bytes;
    pc = fopen (FILE_COMPETIDOR, "rb");
    if (pc == NULL)
    {
    return -1;
    }
    fseek (pc,0,2);
    bytes = ftell (pc);
    fclose (pc);

    return bytes / sizeof (struct competidor);
}

if (pos == 3)
{
    FILE *pc;
    int bytes;
    pc = fopen (FILE_RESULTADO, "rb");
    if (pc == NULL)
    {
    return -1;
    }
    fseek (pc,0,2);
    bytes = ftell (pc);
    fclose (pc);

    return bytes / sizeof (struct resultado);
}

if (pos == 4)
{
    FILE *pc;
    int bytes;
    pc = fopen (FILE_PODIO, "rb");
    if (pc == NULL)
    {
    return -1;
    }
    fseek (pc,0,2);
    bytes = ftell (pc);
    fclose (pc);

    return bytes / sizeof (struct resultado);
}

return 0;
}

 void copiar_archivo(int pos , carrera *a, competidor *b, resultado *c, 
 podio *d, int cant)
{

if (pos == 2)
{
    FILE *pc;
    pc = fopen (FILE_COMPETIDOR, "rb");
    if (pc == NULL)
    {
        color_error();
        cout << "Error de archivo";
        system ("pause > nul");
        system ("cls");
        color_original();
        return;
    }
fread (b, sizeof (struct competidor), cant, pc);
fclose (pc);
}

if (pos == 4)
{
    FILE *pc;
    pc = fopen (FILE_PODIO, "rb");
    if (pc == NULL)
    {
        color_error();
        cout << "Error de archivo";
        system ("pause > nul");
        system ("cls");
        color_original();
        return;
    }

fread (d, sizeof (struct podio), cant, pc);
fclose (pc);
}

}

void ordenar_competidores (int pos, competidor *b, int cant)
{
int i, j, posmin;
competidor aux;

if (pos == 1)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < cant-1 ; i++)
    {
        posmin = i;
        for (j=i+1; j < cant; j++)
        {
            if (b[j].anio_debut < b[posmin].anio_debut)
            {
                posmin=j;
            }

        }
        aux.anio_debut = b[i].anio_debut;
        b[i].anio_debut = b[posmin].anio_debut;
        b[posmin].anio_debut=aux.anio_debut;

    }
}

if (pos == 2)
{
    for (i = 0 ; i < cant-1 ; i++)
    {
        posmin = i;
        for (j=i+1; j < cant; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(b[j].nombre, b[posmin].nombre)<0)
            {
                posmin=j;
            }

        }
        aux = b[i];
        b[i] = b[posmin];
        b[posmin]=aux;

    }
}


}

void mostrar_ordenado (int pos, int pos2)

{
carrera *a;
competidor *b;
resultado *c;
podio *d;

if (pos == 2)
{
   int registros;

    registros = contar_registros(2);

    b = (struct competidor *) malloc(registros * sizeof (competidor));
    if (b == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    copiar_archivo(2,a,b,c,d, registros);
    ordenar_competidores(pos2,b, registros);
    mostrar_vector(2,a,b,c,d, registros);
    free(b);
    return;
}

if (pos == 4)
{
    int registros;
    registros = contar_registros(4);

    d = (struct podio *) malloc(registros * sizeof (podio));
    if (d == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    registros = contar_registros(4);
    copiar_archivo(4, a, b, c, d, registros);
    ordenar_podio(d, registros);
    mostrar_vector(5, a, b, c, d, registros);
    free(d);
    return;
}

}
```

Les pido por favor que dirijan su atención a la función "mostrar_ordenado". Resulta ser que recientemente tuve que añadir una estructura mas al proyecto (Podio) y para ello declaro variables "d" de la estructura "podio" en todas las funciones que la necesiten. Mi problema es las llamadas que tengo en la función "mostrar_ordenado" para la función "copiar_archivo" (Fíjense que hay 2 por que el parámetro "pos" es el que decide como se va a utilizar). Desde que añadí la "d" para adaptar las llamadas al uso de la estructura de podio, cada vez que compilo el proyecto me salen estas advertencias:

warning: 'a' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|

warning: 'b' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|

warning: 'c' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|

warning: 'd' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]|

Se que tiene que ver con que las variables no son inicializadas correctamente, pero ya busque bastante y simplemente no doy con la causa del problema. Lo peor es que ahora cuando intento utilizar estas funciones para ordenar, mi programa "explota" (Antes de añadir la estructura de podio todo funcionada perfectamente).

Si hace falta aclarar : Estoy usando CodeBlocks 16.01 y el compilador de C++ es el GNU GCC.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar a encontrar la causa exacta de este problema? perdón por hacerlos leer mucho pero es que intenté dejar esta pregunta lo mas comprensible que se pueda. Quizá sea una tontería que se arregla en 2 segundos y yo aquí complicándome la vida en vano, pero bueno, eso tiene ser nuevo en c++...

Comment: Asigna `NULL` a `a`, `b`, `c` y `d`, para lo demás, revisa la lógica de tu programa, hay muchas cosas con problemas por ahí...

Comment: De acuerdo con NaCl, ademas ¿donde esta la función mostrar_vector?

Answer (score 2):

Tu código no es C++ sino C, que el programa compile en C++ se debe única y exclusivamente a la compatibilidad existente entre ambos lenguajes. No es C++ porque no haces uso de ninguna característica propia de C++:

- Usas `#define FILE_CARRERA` en vez de `static const std::string FileCarrera`
- Usas `FILE` en vez de `std::ifstream`
- Usas `malloc` en vez de `new`
- Usas `sizeof(struct carrera)` en vez de `sizeof(carrera)`
- Usas `char*` (o `char[]`) en vez de `std::string`
- Usas `competidor*` en vez de `std::vector<competidor>`

Así que lo siento, aunque el programa llegue a generarse con un compilador de C++, tu código **no** es C++. Por mucho que tengas un par de usos de `std::cout` yo al menos no entiendo este programa como C++.

Por otro lado, tu programa está plagado de problemas por los que no va a funcionar:

**fseek**

`fseek (pc,0,2);` es un error en toda regla. Para empezar, si miramos la documentación nos encontramos con lo siguiente:

> Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability).

Es decir, la implementación de SEEK_END en `fseek` no está garantizada y esto es así porque es problemática. En el caso de los ficheros abiertos en modo binario puede suceder que el buffer de lectura sea más grande que el contenido del fichero (no entraré en detalles aquí, Internet está plagada de documentación) y ello va a provocar que el cálculo que haces para detectar el número de elementos falle sin remedio.

¿Cómo conocer entonces el número de registros? puedes optar por añadir el número al inicio del fichero, después un salto de línea y a continuación todos los registros serializados. También puedes usar un segundo fichero para almacenar esa información... las posibilidades son enormes.

**código duplicado**

La función `contar_registros` trata 4 casos diferentes... y todos ellos son sospechosamente idénticos. Mantener código duplicado es una muy mala idea.

Esta práctica se encuentra en todas las funciones publicadas, deberias evitar este tipo de problemas.

**uso incorrecto de tipos**

La función `contar_registros` admite un entero... un entero que está acotado a 4 elementos. ¿No sería mejor usar un enumerado para que quede claro el rango de valores que admite y para qué sirve cada uno? Hay que intentar que las interfaces sean lo más autoexplicativas posibles para prevenir todo tipo de errores.

**Gestión incorrecta del flujo del programa**

La gestión de los casos (seguimos en + `contar_registros` la estás haciendo con `if` simples. Lo suyo sería usar `switch` o, a malas, una cadena de `if-else if`. Mejora la claridad y evita errores involuntarios.

**warning 'X' may be used uninitialized in this function**

Si tienes un código tal que:

```
int main()
{
  int a;
  std::cout << a;
}
```

¿Qué valor tiene `a`? No puedes saberlo y eso es un problema porque debido a eso el programa se comportará de forma arbitraria (cada vez que lo ejecutes podría devolver un valor diferente). Las variables **deben ser inicializadas** antes de su primer uso y esta regla es especialmente importante en el caso de los punteros:

```
int main()
{
  int* puntero;

  if( !ptr )
    ptr = new int[10]; // Se reservara la memoria??
}
```

En el caso de los punteros, por convención, se entiende que no apuntan a nada válido si los mismos apuntan a la posición de memoria 0. Esta medida se toma porque es imposible determinar, a partir de cualquier otro valor del puntero, si el mismo apunta a una dirección de memoria válida o no.

El compilador en este caso te está avisando de que presumiblemente las variables indicadas están siendo usadas sin haberlas inicializado. El compilador cada vez ayuda más al programador al detectar errores tontos y problemáticos a partes iguales y este es un claro ejemplo.

Solucionarlo es tan sencillo como inicializar los punteros:

```
void mostrar_ordenado (int pos, int pos2)
{
  carrera *a = 0;
  competidor *b = 0;
  resultado *c = 0;
  podio *d = 0;
```